# How to create a symbolic link with the api.jar file in unix?

Tags: unix, symlink

I have jar file for eg abc-api.10.1.jar; i want to create symlink so that next time new jar comes like abc-api.10.2.jar i just point the link to new jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On RHEL you could use something like this :`ln -s <real object> <symlink name>`

`ln -s abc-api.10.1.jar current_jar`

Comment: whenever you update the jar link, do not forget to restart the java process